# Do Parse service requires Google Account?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need to make an application which contains push alerts but target device doesn't implemented Google Play Services and they're not connected to Google Account.

So I tried to find solution, and I finally found Parse service.

But while I tried to connect my app to Parse, they required the receiver such like

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="{PACKAGE_NAME}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Isn't these receivers are used for GCM?
Then do Parse service uses GCM and the target device needs Google Account or Google Play Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

From [official guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android)

> The Parse Android SDK chooses a reasonable default configuration so that you do not have to worry about GCM registration ids, sender ids, or API keys. In particular, the SDK will automatically register your app for push at startup time using Parse's sender ID (1076345567071) and will store the resulting registration ID in the deviceToken field of the app's current ParseInstallation.